# jQuery validation with custom CSS checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I'm using [JQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and have styled my checkbox with custom css styles.

For my custom checkbox I'm using pure CSS as shown below. The issue I'm having is that when it validates it doesn't display the error message.

I'm assuming because I have to use `display:none` for the custom styled checkbox it can't find the input to add the error message label to it.

My other form fields work fine with the validation messages with similar HTML but not using custom image replacement css like for the checkbox.

Any idea on how I can get both to work (custom checkbox style AND validation)?
Thanks

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label.checkboxLbl
{
background-image: url(../img/checkbox.png);
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.checkboxLbl
{
background-position: 0 -18px;
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

<div class="checkbox mycheckbox">
        <span class="tncLabel"><strong>I have read and accept the <a class=
        "underLined" href="tnc" target="_blank">Terms and
        Conditions</a>*</strong></span> 
        <input class=
        "form-control css-checkbox" id="checkboxG1" name="checkboxG1" required=
        "required" title="Please accept our terms and conditions" type=
        "checkbox" value="1">
        <label class="css-checkbox-label checkboxLbl"
        for="checkboxG1"></label>
        <br style="clearfix">
</div>
```

I've also tried adding the following but still no luck.

```
$("#registryForm").validate({
   ignore: []  // enables validation of hidden elements
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because by default the hidden elements are not validated, so you can use the `ignore` option to validate the hidden field like

```
$('form').validate({
    //other properties
    ignore: ':hidden:not(:checkbox)'
})
```

You may also have to override the `errorPlacement, if you want to customize the error placement.

```
//your form here
$('form').validate({
    //other properties
    ignore: ':hidden:not(:checkbox)',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is(":checkbox")) {
            alert('validating')
            element.closest('.checkbox').append(error)
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you Arun, however it's still not working :( no validation message displays

Comment: My other inputs get the following added although this checkbox doesn't. `<label id="name-error" class="error" for="name">Please enter your name</label>`

Comment: just did but still no luck :( I even tried with changing the form to the form ID `#registryForm` and the `.closest` selector. Funnily enough it doesn't even `alert`!

Comment: Ok now I got it to alert by taking the function out of the `document.ready` function but still no error added. Getting close :)

Comment: Arun, thank you so much! Got it working with your help :) I can't load the fiddle for some reason but it's working perfectly!! Accepted your answer.