# Displaying HTML5 validation message for custom checkbox

Tags: css, html, forms, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

My sign-up form uses HTML5 validation to validate that required fields have been completed.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="https://www.salesforce.com" method="POST" id="signup">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first_name">First name</label>
                    <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input id="tou" name="tou" type="checkbox" value="1" required="required"/>
                        I have read and agree to the terms of use.
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've replaced the default checkbox with a custom .svg checkbox using CSS.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
    content: url(/static/img/unchecked.svg);
    visibility: visible;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
    content: url(/static/img/checked.svg);
}
```

While the HTML5 validation works with other fields, I can't get it to work for the custom checkbox.  I tried the methods shown in [jQuery validation with custom CSS checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555168/jquery-validation-with-custom-css-checkbox) without success.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you showing us the css if you are having trouble with the jquery validation?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are setting required as an attribute? Why not set it in the same way you're setting required on the text input?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I wanted to show how I hid the default checkbox in case it was necessary for the solution.

Comment: @macksol Good catch.  There's no reason to set required as an attribute.

Answer (score 4):

The default HTML5 validation error message is not visible, because you hide it with:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xfosb27j/2/

Comment: Thanks for this - helpful to me years on from you answering.